# Python: Output of the given code

Tags: python

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]

for a[-1] in a:

    print(a[-1])
```

I'm new to python, so can anyone explain the output of this code.

Output

```
0 1 2 2
```

`a[-1]` indicates the last element `3`, so shouldn't the output be `3 3 3 3` ?

Comment: @Kshitij Grag Gave a good explanation, but I just want to note this is very convoluted and is hard to understand, you probably meant to declare a new variable as the iterator (e.g. for x in a).

Comment: This code looks horrible, where ever you got that from, you should look somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should help clarify:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]

for a[-1] in a:

    print(a)
```

which outputs:

```
[0, 1, 2, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 2]
```

So what is happening is each time you go past the loop the list type is iterated upon starting at the start of your iterator (`a`), which brings the next item of the list into memory at the name you declared (`a[-1]`). Because you are changing the same thing you're iterating through, you get your unexpected result. Focusing on the last two outputs you can see that you write `2` into `a[-1]` and then iterate so you're looking at `a[4]` (which is also `a[-1]` in this case) but that was just rewritten to `2`, hence your output.

What you probably wanted was something like:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]

for foo in a:

    print(foo)
```

Answer (score 2):

What happens is that a[-1] is being used as the variable in which each element is being stored.
So for a[-1] in a: iterates over each element in a and stores the value in a[-1] i.e a[3]

As the last value being stored in a[3] is a[2] i.e 2  ... The output is 0,1,2,2
Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

This code is equivalent tu the following:
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]

for x in a:

```
a[-1] = x

print(a[-1])
```

so a[-1] is changing